# What is the correct way to include component that is used in material dialog (Angular with Ivy)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component that I want to show inside the [material dialog][1]. They say it must be specified inside `entryComponents` of some component, however `entryComponents`.

I have included the component via importing its module (bellow).

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CreateUrlComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,

        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatSelectModule,
    ],
})
export class CreateUrlModule { }
```

However, I have a problem. When the dialog appears on the screen, it seems, like the styles for it are not loaded (or something) see gif bellow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeIgp.jpg

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your question right. the entryComponents should be used like this:

```
@NgModule({
imports:[
    CommonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSelectModule,

 ],
declarations:[
   CreateUrlComponent,
],
exports:[
   CreateUrlComponent,
],
entryComponents: [
   CreateUrlComponent,
]
})
 export class ModalModule{
}
```

Comment: Even though `entryComponents` are deprecated?

Comment: in my application, I'm using entryComponents. I hadn't noticed that it has become obsolete. are you having problems using the dialog without the entryComponents?

Comment: I could not get it working with `entryComponents`, nor without it... I had to include a module :/